# Magick.NET takes a long time loading PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using Magick.NET to grab the first page of a PDF and convert it to a thumbnail.  It's working well, but for larger files with lots of images and many pages, it takes a long time to load up the PDF itself.  Is there a way to tell Magick.NET to ignore any pages after the first one?

I am loading them in directly from a steam after a PDF is uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the pages to read with the FrameIndex and FrameCount properties of the MagickReadSettings object.

```
using (MagickImageCollection collection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
  MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
  settings.FrameIndex = 0; // First page
  settings.FrameCount = 1; // Number of pages

  collection.Read("Snakeware.pdf", settings);
}
```

I have also updated the documentation here: https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20PDF

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using 6.8.5.402 - this version doesn't have these Framing settings.  Looks like I'll need to update to a later version. Do you know which version they were introduced in?

Comment: Note to others, you might not get Intellisense on those Frame properties. Just forge ahead.

Comment: How to know settings.FrameCount (PDF Page Count) before actually reading it? Maybe there is a quick method to check page cunt using Magic.NET?

Comment: You can now use PdfInfo.Create to get the total number of pages.